# how to make button visible on hover of image

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

i have a image and button, i need button to be visible only when i hover img or that button itself..note:the button is places at bottom of image

```
<div class="sixcont">      
              <img  src="{{ slide.image }}" alt="" width="95%">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="quickview" data-toggle="modal" attr.data-target="{{'#'+slide.slug}}">quick preview</button>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use css to resolve your issue:

```
.sixcont > button {
display: none;
}

.sixcont:hover > button {
display: block;
}
```

Also, in libraries like tailwind you can find visibility and hover utils, but I don't know about those utils in bootstrap.

```css
.sixcont > button {
display: none;
}

.sixcont:hover > button {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="sixcont">      
    <img  src="https://picsum.photos/23"/" alt="" width="200px">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="quickview" data-toggle="modal" attr.data-target="{{'#'+slide.slug}}">quick preview</button>
</div>
```

Comment: it is working but  button display when button hover is lagging

Answer (score 1):

Good news! you don't need Js for that.
You can use the css sibling selector `+` to achieve what you want.

```css
button{
  display:none;
}

img:hover + button{
  display:block
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/100"/>
<button>Button</button>
```

Comment: button cannot be used in this scenario

Answer (score 1):

An "Angular way" is always use a variable and use the event (mouseover) (mouseout). NOTE: Is necesary that the button is "inside" the img

```
isVisible:boolean=false;

<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="..." (mouseover)="isVisible=true" (mouseout)="isVisible=false">
  <button (click)="doSomeThing()" *ngIf="isVisible">click</button>
</div>

.wrapper{
  position:relative;
}
.wrapper button{
  position:absolute;
  top:1rem;
  left:1rem;
}
```